# How to prevent conda updating packages when using 2 `requirements.txt`

Tags: python, pip, conda

## Context

I have to install two packages from Gitlab (not available on any `conda` or `pip` channels due to copyright restrictions).
The requirements of the first package contain

```
numpy>=1.16,<1.17
```

The requirements of the second state just

```
numpy
```

Here is a simplified MWE of what I'm doing:

```
conda create -n test2
conda activate test2
conda install "numpy>=1.16,<1.17"
conda install --freeze-installed numpy
```

## Result

Conda first installs a 1.16.* version of `numpy` and then wants to update it to v. 1.18, when the last command is launched:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/user/miniconda3/envs/test2

  added / updated specs:
    - numpy


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    numpy-1.18.5               |   py38h8854b6b_0         5.2 MB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         5.2 MB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  numpy                               1.16.5-py38h95a1406_0 --> 1.18.5-py38h8854b6b_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

## Expected behavior

When I install both, I would like to just have `numpy=1.16.*` installed in the end.

## Question

The `--freeze-installed` option seems to only apply to dependencies. I was not able to find a similar option that would not update the main package, if the new requirement does not conflict with the installed verion. Something like `--no-update`. Does anyone have ideas on how this can be achieved?

Surely, I can inverse the order of the `install` commands in this particular MWE, but it does not solve the general problem of having 2 requirements files with different but compatible specifications.

Comment: Hmh, not sure I understood your question correctly: Are you installing with `conda install` as in your example? If so you can add as many packages as you want and conda will try to figure out a valid way to resolve it. `conda install numpy "numpy>=1.16,<1.17"` would install a numpy=1.16.x. If you have multiple files, you can [pass the `--file=` argument multiple times](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Named%20Arguments).

Comment: What version is when conda _updates it to the latest version_?

Comment: @Evgeny I get an update to `1.18`. Updated the question.

Comment: @cel My problem is that the next time I add the requirements file, in the second command, the previous constraints are overridden: conda will install 1.18 instead of keeping 1.16.*.

Comment: @cel But it's a good point to give several requirements files. I will try it.

Comment: Looks like combining the requirements is a way to go

Comment: I checked it and it works. @cel, if you post it as an answer, I will accept it!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, why not just manually create a requirements file and build the environment from that?

Comment: @AMC I need an automatic way for an end-user to combine `requirements.txt` files from different packages, so I’m doing that in a script. The `requirements.txt` may evolve in time, so I cannot just do it once manually.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś Oh, that sounds like it could be tough.  It might be interesting, though, is your work available anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass all requirements to a single `conda install` command instead of two subsequent calls, conda's solver will try to satisfy all of the dependencies at once. This will give you the expected outcome that the dependencies `numpy>=1.16,<1.17` and `numpy` get resolved to a `1.16.x` version of numpy.

When you are working with multiple requirement files, you can [pass the `--file` argument multiple times](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Named%20Arguments) to provide all the dependencies in one go.